# How can i query track number on web site?

Tags: php, numbers, query-string, tracking

Package Track number: RC081226418HK

Package tracking site: http://www1.ptt.gov.tr/tr/interaktif/kayitliposta-yd_yeniweb.php

I want query on simple link.

Example: http://www1.ptt.gov.tr/tr/interaktif/kayitliposta-yd_yeniweb.php?RC081226418HK

but it's not work..

Do you have any method ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
$get_key = array_keys($_GET);
$track_number =  $get_key[0];
echo $track_number;
```